# checking if facebook-sdk android giving null value for user data before calling getProperty()

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I searched I can't find any solution for this problem.
I have made graph-request in facebook SDK 3.5.
When I try to get data using getProperty("Property_name") and if its value is null maybe user didn't set the favourite sports in his profile

Example: 
**Code:For buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) Method**

```
    // I have used all The mandatory permissions

    Map<String, String> map;

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try {

        map.put("ID", user.getId().toString());

        String athletes = user.getProperty("favorite_athletes").toString();
        String fav_teams = user.getProperty("favorite_teams").toString();
        String sports = user.getProperty("sports").toString();
        String education = user.getProperty("education").toString();
        String work = user.getProperty("work").toString();

        map.put("athletes", athletes);
        map.put("fav teams", fav_teams);
        map.put("sports", sports);
        map.put("education", education);
        map.put("work", work);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG + " Error:", e.toString());
    }

    //PassData is Interface object send data in Map<Strin String> format to Activity launching this Fragment
    try {
        passData(map); //Passing data through Interface
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG + " Error 2:", e.toString());         
    }
}`

Error
StackTrace : 

`java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.main.hotspot.MainFragment.buildUserInfoDisplay(MainFragment.java:177)
at com.main.hotspot.MainFragment.access$1(MainFragment.java:162)
at com.main.hotspot.MainFragment$2.onCompleted(MainFragment.java:77)
at com.facebook.Request$1.onCompleted(Request.java:269)
at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1669)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

MainFragment Error:(646): java.lang.NullPointerException`
```

line 177 is where I call for sports data:

**String sports = user.getProperty("sports").toString(); // line 177**

if sports property is not present in response so getProperty() will give NullPointerException.
and further I tried to pass data in Map format from fragment to Activity launching this fragment by defining Interface. But because of Exception I can't pass data to activity. I want to process it in Activity.

how can I check before calling the getProperty() that this value is present in user object.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace from your logs?

Comment: @MingLi I have added Stacktrace. It shows error at line where i call for sports data. As one of user didn't like any sports I think thats why it is giving null value and throws **NullPointerException**

Comment: let me know if there is any check to know which attributes are returned in user object of facebook so I can call getProperty() for non Empty property only !! As app crashes at the Point I call getProperty() for non existing attribute. I used try catch that makes app not to crash but further execution doesn't work after NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're calling .toString on a potentially null object, and is not really related to the SDK at all. Common java idiom is to protect your calls with null checks. Something like:

```
Object athletes = user.getProperty("favorite_athletes");
if (athletes != null) {
  map.put("athletes", athletes.toString());
}
...
```