# android facebook sdk returns email null

Tags: android, facebook

My app before used this code and it worked but it stopped work about yesterday, dont know why.
I can get name and picture. But email is null.

```
 List<String> permisions = Arrays.asList(
            "email");

    Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, permisions , new Session.StatusCallback() {

          // callback when session changes state
          @Override
          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {

              // make request to the /me API
              Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null) {
                    String name = user.getFirstName();
                    String email = (String)user.getProperty("email");
                    System.out.println("Email: "+email);
                    System.out.println("Name: "+name);

                  }
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure it stopped working (ie that user really has an email address associated)? Also what you get using `response.getGraphObject().getProperty("email")`?

Comment: yeaaa for other facebook account i got email, but anyway i should got email for that account too because i checked it has one...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that a user may have an email set in their Facebook profile but may set it to private meaning even though they have it setup, you can't retrieve it and in this case, you will get a null value. You might want to check for null first before using the property else the code flow will stop there and nothing will happen, no error or anything though you will get NPE. Check this: [checking if facebook-sdk android giving null value for user data before calling getProperty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534834/checking-if-facebook-sdk-android-giving-null-value-for-user-data-before-calling)